# IF ELSE statement in SQL query for new column using SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

My problem is if sales.cost is < 100 then 'special'  else if  sales.cost => 100 'Regular'

Here is my query

```
SELECT 
    List.Item, List.Department, List.Group, List.Cost, 
    [Query 2].Sales, [Query 2].Revenue, special 
FROM 
    [Sales Units], List 
INNER JOIN 
    [Query 2] ON List.Item = [Query 2].Item;
```

The last column is addition and here is some more explanation.

```
    Special       if List.Cost
    Special      Less than 100
    Regular      100 or greater
```

I gooled alot but found case as a solution but if does not provide suitable answer i will be thankfull if you solve little puzzle

Here is case that I used

```
SELECT 
    List.Item, List.Department, List.Group, List.Cost, 
    [Query 2].Sales, [Query 2].Revenue, Special,
    CASE
       WHEN [Query 2].Sales < 100 
          THEN Special = 'Special' 
       WHEN [Query 2].Sales => 100 
          THEN Special = 'Regular' 
    END
FROM 
    [Sales Units], List 
INNER JOIN 
    [Query 2] ON List.Item = [Query 2].Item
ORDER BY 
    List.Item;
```

Comment: (1) Are you using SQL Server or MS Access?  I removed the incompatible database tags, so you can add the right on.  (2) How did the `case` not work?  You should include your attempt  (3) Why are you mixing archaic join syntax (commas) with proper explicit `join` syntax?

Comment: your issue here is `then Special = 'special'`, the new field name must be provided before or after field logic: `Special = case...end` or `case when...end as Special`

Comment: @GordonLinoff is write but tell me how to display its `l.Cost` feild as currency format with 2 decimal

Comment: Please answer @GordonLinoff's first and very important question. SQL is a language of many dialects. `CASE` statements are not valid in MS Access' Jet/ACE SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS Access doesn't support `case`.  You need to use `iif()` instead:

```
SELECT l.Item, l.Department, l.Group, l.Cost,
       q.Sales, q.Revenue,
       IIF(l.Cost < 100, 'Special', 'Regular') as special 
FROM List as l INNER JOIN
     [Query 2] as q
     ON l.Item = q.Item;
```

I don't think you need `[Sales Units]` in the query.

In SQL Server -- or any other databases, really -- you should use `case` rather than database-specific functions.

Comment: also set a feild to currency with 2 decimal any idea

Comment: like `l.Cost` display as currency with 2 decimal

Comment: To format numeric column to currency in MS Access use [Ccur()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Type-Conversion-Functions-8ebb0e94-2d43-4975-bb13-87ac8d1a2202) which aligns currency type to user's CPU locale settings.

Comment: ` FormatCurrency(l.Cost,2,-2,-2,-2) as Cost,`  because of that but you are right happy

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT l.Item, 
       l.Department, 
       l.Group, 
       FormatCurrency(l.Cost,2,-2,-2,-2) as Cost,
       q.Sales, 
       q.Revenue , 
       CASE WHEN l.Cost < 100 THEN 'Special'
       ELSE 'REGULAR' END AS 'Special'
FROM [List] l INNER JOIN [Query 2] q ON l.Item = q.Item;
```

For `SQL` use `FORMAT(l.Cost,'C','en-us')`

Comment: @GORDON LINOF answer is write can you tell me how to write the cost value as i commented the `l.Cost` as 2 decimal and currency format

Comment: I have edited the answer. For more information see the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Comment: `#Error`  returned

Comment: If this for Access? If so, let me know if you want me to modify the answer or if you want to try yourself by using FormatCurrency instead. See here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FormatCurrency-Function-5a846882-d970-4a67-8da9-4e87a416b3d1

Comment: 'C' automatically converts to general date

Comment: For MS Access FormatCurrency(l.Cost,2,-2,-2,-2). Click the link above in my comments for more info.

Comment: @EngrNouman  . . . You tagged the question MS Access and then accepted an answer that doesn't work in that database.

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple:

```
[Special] = iif(IsNull(List.Cost, 0) < 100, 'Special', 'Regular')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may modify your query like this:

```
SELECT List.Item, List.Department, List.Group, List.Cost, [Query 2].Sales,
[Query 2].Revenue ,
```

---

```
CASE
       WHEN    [Query 2].Sales <  100   THEN   'Special'
       WHEN    [Query 2].Sales >= 100   THEN   'Regular' 

END as Special
```

---

```
FROM [Sales Units], List INNER JOIN [Query 2] ON List.Item = [Query 2].Item;
```

Hope it helps. :)